# Optimizely Media Controller

Tags: episerver, optimizely

Im trying to use a controller in Optimizely (The artist formerly known as Episerver) to customize how I render media items, but the controller does not seem to get called:

```
public class MediaController : PartialContentController<MediaData>
{
   private readonly UrlResolver UrlResolver;

   public MediaController(UrlResolver urlResolver) => this.UrlResolver = urlResolver;

   public override ActionResult Index(MediaData currentContent)
   {
       switch (currentContent)
       {
            //Do some logic here
       }
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that this PartialContentController would get fired for any model the inherited from MediaData. Instead its rendering a default img tag. I cant seem to intercept that process and use some custom image markup no matter what. How do I force Optimizely to use my controller?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Episerver chooses another controller to render the content, instead of your controller.

You could try splitting this into four separate controllers, one for each media type (with the last being fall back to MediaData). This will make your controllers "more specific" controllers, and more eligible to be chosen for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to call it from a page/block.  If so I'd use a service/helper in the page/block controller to get the model data and then create an image view model and return itg into a view that way

id general stick to a rule of use controller for pages, block, page partial.  YOu may have a good use case though?

Comment: This issue is how I was calling it. The image field is a content reference with a UIHint of Image. In this case, it uses the display template called Image.cshtml. So, in this case just needed to create the display template. The controller gets called if I add the image to a ContentArea